# Angular 2 - Run Unit Tests on form submission

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

Can I run unit tests on form submission in angular 2. Actually I am very new to angular 2 and in learning stage so anyone please help me to find it out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What would be a plausible use case for this?

Comment: login component

Comment: And what would a login component need unit tests at runtime for?

Comment: Actually i didnt have any idea about it and i dont know what am doing.

Comment: i just want to know is there possible that unit tests runs when i changed the values of login form or just try to loggedIn.